# Lumen Getting Header Keys from Request

Tags: .htaccess, api, lumen, request-headers, lumen-5.4

I'm implementing **Authentication** in **API** using **Lumen** framework. I'm passing **api_token** in the header on localhost it's working fine. while uploading on **Linux Server**, it gives a null value in **api_token header**. I'm using **postman** to check the response

Here's my AuthMiddleware@handle code to check the value.

```
echo $request->header("api_token");
```

I googled it most of the time and found that public/.htaccess changes required but not worked for me.

```
# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
```

on the end of my .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

I don't know how to configure apache2 for request headers.

Comment: what is your js script, to pass the api_token header?

Comment: For that am using postman to pass api_token in header

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `underscore` should be avoided for the request header key. `hyphen` is more common and you should rename the request header key to **api-token**. According to [Apache 2.4 new features](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/new_features_2_4.html):

> Translation of headers to environment variables is more strict than
>   before to mitigate some possible cross-site-scripting attacks via
>   header injection. **Headers containing invalid characters** (including
>   underscores) **are now silently dropped**. Environment Variables in Apache
>   has some pointers on how to work around broken legacy clients which
>   require such headers. (This affects all modules which use these
>   environment variables.)